# Changing UserForm frame font size in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a `UserForm` in VBA for some data entry. I have segregated the input boxes using a few frames.

I want to have the labels for these frames in a larger font size than the default so that they can stand out from the rest of the form.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: In design mode: Left click the frame to select it. Then in properties pane click font. You can set it there.

Comment: I think I have looked at that box a dozen times and not clicked on it. Facepalm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to change it when initializing the userform

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Frame1
        .Font.Size = 20
        .Font.Bold = True
        .ForeColor = vbGreen
    End With
End Sub
```